# Incorrect deserialisation of ZoneDateTime from JSON with ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

i'm receiving `long = 1417471200000` which should be **2017** year, but, when ZoneDateTime is deserialized its value is `+48908-06-13 16:00:00`
i'm already have maven dependency of

```
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
<version>2.6.5</version>
```

Where i made a mistake?

also, when i deserialize this wrong `ZoneDateTime` object to `long`, its value is back again `1417471200000`

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be 2014? The unix timestamp `1417471200` (dropping the last 3 zeros) is in 2014. Basically, you're getting a time in millis, but passing it to something that expects time in seconds.

Comment: yeah, it may be in 2014, i have multiple of Long's
Yes, it really looks like ZoneDateTime consumes it like seconds, not millis.
Make answer to a topic, i will make it right

Comment: Java 8 time classes store seconds and nanos of seconds. Taking millis would be strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time you have here appears to be in milliseconds:

```
1417471200      = Mon Dec  1 22:00:00 GMT 2014
1417471200000   = Sat Nov 15 16:00:00 GMT 46887
```

You're passing the milliseconds to something that expects time in seconds.