# Incorrect deserialisation of OffsetDateTime from JSON with ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson

this is the same issue, as here
[Incorrect deserialisation of ZoneDateTime from JSON with ObjectMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026453/incorrect-deserialisation-of-zonedatetime-from-json-with-objectmapper)

but enabling `objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());`
or `objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);`

doesnt help.
I'm receiving millis and need them to ve converted to OffsetDateTime
currently i'm receiving `"+49053-07-23T16:00:00.000+0000"`

Comment: "I'm receiving millis" - so why are you deserializing them as nanoseconds?

Comment: no, im not reading them as nanos, it's reading them as seconds, so  need to tell OM divide received value by 1000.
How may i do this?

Comment: Well in the latter case with `DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS` it certainly looks like you're reading it as nanoseconds. Are you saying that gave the exact same output? It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] for us to experiment with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in bad configuration of my deserializator.
It was configured properly, with `DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false` option, but then reconfigured to a default.
ObjectMapper support deserialization of `OffsetDatetime` from millis out of the box